# Is it possible to Install .net 4.7 version on my machine when .net 4.8 is already installed?

Tags: .net, .net-4.7, .net-4.8

I have the following .net versions on my machine. I started working on a .net project which's targetframework is 4.7. When I tried to install .net 4.7, I got this error **".NET Framework 4.7 or a later update is already installed on this computer."**

Is it possible to Install .net 4.7 version on my machine when .net 4.8 is already installed ?

```
PSChildName                      Version        Release
-----------                      -------        -------
v2.0.50727                       2.0.50727.4927
v3.0                             3.0.30729.4926
Windows Communication Foundation 3.0.4506.4926
Windows Presentation Foundation  3.0.6920.4902
v3.5                             3.5.30729.4926
Client                           4.8.03761      528049
Full                             4.8.03761      528049
Client                           4.0.0.0
```

Comment: No. The .NET Framework runtime is always using the latest version included in Windows. You cannot install older version than the version included in Windows. For example, Windows 10 1809 has .NET Framework 4.7.2 installed, therefore you cannot install v4.6 on this Windows.

Comment: More Clarifications on the question: The project that I started working is targeted into .net 4.7. (as Target Framework 4.7). Since, I don't have 4.7 installed on my machine, it asked me to download the .net 4.7 or downgrade the project's target framework's .net version to a lower version which I have on my machine. When I tried to install .net 4.7 on my computer, it didnt allow me to install .net 4.7 as I have already installed .net 4.8 (higher version). I just wanted to know whether a lower .net version can be installed on my machine even though I have a higher version

Answer (score 12):

If I am guessing correctly you need a Developer Pack for .NET 4.7.

The SDK/Developer Pack and the Runtime are not the same.

Know that a machine could be able to run applications that target a given .NET version but not build for it, if it has a compatible Runtime but not the particular SDK (software development kit).

---

Using Visual Studio Installer, you should be able to add the development tools:

[image: Visual Studio Installer]

See [Install the .NET Framework for developers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/install/guide-for-developers).

You can also get the SDKs/Developer Packs at [Download .NET SDKs for Visual Studio](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/visual-studio-sdks).

---

Did you try installing the [Developer Pack for .NET 4.7](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/thank-you/net47-developer-pack)? Does that solve the problem? *I think you only did try to install the .NET 4.7 Runtime, not the Developer Pack.*

As per installing the Runtime , as you have found out, the installer won't let you. If you really need the old Runtime※ you would have to uninstall the newer version and the install then old one.

※: Which is unlikely, given that the Runtimes up to .NET 4.8 keep backwards compatibility to .NET 4.5. See [Version compatibility in the .NET Framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/version-compatibility) before you decide going on uninstalling.

Comment: CMIIW, I think the question is on installing .NET Framework runtime, not the .NET Framework SDK.

Comment: @EriawanKusumawardhono OP says "I started working on a .net project which's targetframework is 4.7", if there is something OP needs, it is the SDK.

Comment: Yes, then he focused on asking the problem of installing .NET Fx 4.7 on a machine that has v4.8. I admit his question is not very clear on asking the exact problem.

Comment: @EriawanKusumawardhono this is my hypothesis: OP got the project, wanted to start working on it, could not. OP sees that it requires *something something* .NET 4.7 *something something*, so OP downloaded the .NET 4.7 runtime installer, but it could not install because the machine has the .NET 4.8 runtime already installed. So, OP asked here. It is a bit of XY problem. The problem is X, OP asks for Y. Yet not one obscure enough that we cannot have a reasonable idea of what X was.

Comment: Yes, I'm still not quite sure what exactly the problem is.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. The project that I started working is targeted into .net 4.7. (as Target Framework 4.7). Since, I don't have 4.7 installed on my machine, it asked me to download the .net 4.7 or downgrade the project's target framework's .net version to a lower version which I have on my machine. When I tried to install .net 4.7 on my computer, it didnt allow me to install .net 4.7 as I have already installed .net 4.8 (higher version). I just wanted to know whether a lower .net version can be installed on my machine even though I have a higher version.

Comment: @Theraot Will the program built targeting 4.8 runs in a PC with 4.7 runtime? (assume no new members in 4.8 are used). I guess it would? I have no control of the client runtime.

Comment: @joe You should be able to target 4.7 even if you have a newer SDK (I'll reiterate that the SDK and the runtime are different things). Assuming you can't, you should still be able to specify `supportedRuntime` in `app.config`, see [Version compatibility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/version-compatibility) (also linked in the answer).

Comment: My point is that if my program is already compiled (4.8) and released in binaries. I can't modify it anymore. Would it run on a PC with 4.7 runtime. From this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/versions-and-dependencies#remarks-for-version-45-and-later), it seems it could...

Comment: @joe I believe it will refuse to run it. However, testing beats Internet hearsay.

Answer (score -1):

If you have 4.5.1 installed then you CAN install 4.6.1 but if you already have 4.6.1 then you CANNOT go down to 4.5.1
First, you have to uninstall the latest version (in this example 4.6.1) and then you will be able to install the downgraded version (in this example 4.5.1), otherwise it will give an error.
Once your software is installed for which you are installing down version. Simply download and install the latest version of .Net Framework again.

Answer (score -1):

I faced the exact issue on my machine.

.net Framework 4.8 is installed and I need to install 4.7, I have tried to install 4.7 "**Runtime**" version and it says "***Can't install because 4.7 or later version is already installed on your machine***".

But when I tried with 4.7 Developer Version, it installed successfully.

[image]

So in-short go with Developer Pack, if you need to install Lower Verson of .net Framework.